# Узнать информацию о железе через python3

Tags: python, python-3.6, библиотеки, железо, bios

по заданию нужно только с помощью python3 узнать информацию о марке сопроцессора и его описателях, производителя и название материнки, и производителя, дату и версии биоса. Даны просто две возможные библиотеки subprocess и platform, но они не дают нужного

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скорее всего нужно искать платформо-зависимое решение. В зависимости от того, какая операционка и т.д.

Comment: Я не питонист, но инструмент, которым я пользуюсь - написан на нём. Вот описание кусочка, с помощью которого я могу посмотреть минимум модель матери и инструкции проца: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html А вот вроде как сорц этого модуля: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/setup.py Наверное там есть то, что тебе надо.